# How to Improve the correctness of Handwriting Digit Detection and Recognition with Python, OpenCv and SVM model

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, svm, handwriting-recognition

I have tried many ways to improve the correctness of the handwriting digit detection and recognition, but still have some errors in detection and recognition of some digits. For example, there are only 5 digits written on the paper, but sometimes the output of my code will indicate more than 5 digits detected for certain sample input. I have attached my output and code below. Anyone know what causes this issue?

**Output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
def Load_Test_Digits(TEST_USER_IMG):    
    print('\nLoading "%s for digit recognition" ...\n' % TEST_USER_IMG) #(Output)

    for Load_detect_img in glob.glob(TEST_USER_IMG):

        img = cv2.imread(Load_detect_img)
        # draw rectangle to the image
        draw_rect_matrix = cv2.rectangle(img,(640,560),(1500,670),(0,255,0),2)
        #Make color image as Grayscale
        imggray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        #Crop matrix
        crop_matrix = imggray[560:670, 640:1500]

        kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
        ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(crop_matrix, 127,255,0)
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
        morph_img = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

        #Detect canny 
        canny_edge = cv2.Canny(morph_img, 100, 200)

        #Finding the countours on the image
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(canny_edge.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

        #Sort rectangle
        sorted_matrix = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])

        num_list_matrix = []

        for i, x in enumerate(sorted_matrix):
            if len(contours) == 0:
                number = []

            else:#Get bounding box
                (x,y,w,h)  = cv2.boundingRect(x)
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            
                if (w >= 5 and w <= 150) and (h >= 15 and h <= 120):
                    im_digit = crop_matrix[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                    im_digit = imresize(im_digit,(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
                    hog_img_data = pixels_to_hog_20([im_digit])
                    pred = model.predict(hog_img_data)
                
                    number = (str(int(pred[0])))
                    num_list_matrix.append(number)

        matrix_number = "".join(num_list_matrix)


        print("Matrix Number: ", matrix_number)
```

Comment: Aren't those alternatives? Like "it could be either 6 or 0" in the first case and "it could be either 6 or 4" in the second? I don't know this API or anything about it but I see you get and append `pred[0]`-s. Do you know what else `pred` could tell you?

Comment: What kind of dataset you used for building the model? How many samples were used for training?

Comment: pred is the digit SVM model detected and recognise @tevemadar.

Comment: @stateMachine i self-collect 1000 digit for building the model. and i use 800 sample for training.